# Where do I get a notion about the division in the Calculus book by Michael Spivak?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I started self-education from Calculus by Michael Spivak. But I'm a little bit confused with the first chapter's problems that use division. The division isn't defined in the Basic Properties of Numbers. Should I just assume that: ${a}^{-1} = \dfrac{1}{a}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, negative exponents can be written that way.

See:
https://www.khanacademy.org/math/cc-eighth-grade-math/cc-8th-numbers-operations/cc-8th-pos-neg-exponents/v/negative-exponents

I recommend that you review algebra and trigonometry before you start calculus, it'll make your life a lot easier!

Comment: Yeah, I don't think that I have problems with exponentiation, what confused me is that the division wasn't presented in any form except $a*a^{-1} = 1$ for a≠0, but practice uses division all around the place.

Comment: I see, that must have been frustrating. I believe that in higher levels of math, they tend to try and make their axioms as simple as possible, and I think they like to look at division as multiplying by the inverse and subtracting as adding by a negative. We need to ask a more professional mathematician, however!